# Lexical error in Haskell when concatenating strings

Tags: string, haskell, concatenation, lexical

I am trying to insert a character ('A') into a string in Haskell my code is as follows:

```
split :: Int -> String -> String
split n s 
    |s == [] = s
    |otherwise = let (a,b) = splitAt n s in “A” ++ split n b
```

However, it keeps throwing up " lexical error at character '\8220' " on the otherwise line. Im new to Haskell and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `“` to`"`. It's a different Unicode character. You have `“` which is [left double quation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) while the standard lexical element is the simple quotation mark (`"`)

---

Also, since you're adding a single letter, you can also use `'A' : split n b`